# Packaging systemd without start service on install

Tags: debian, packaging, systemd

I package my software with dpgk and dh-make for create directory and files.
I would like to add systemd support, so I installed dh-systemd.

But, after packaging, I try to install my package, the service is started.
I would like to install my .deb without starting the service.

Here my debian/rules file:

```
%:
dh $@ --with=systemd
override_dh_installinit:
    dh_installinit --name=myapp --no-start
```

I follow this : https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_installinit.1.en.html

I don't understand why the service start

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my similar case working by overriding `dh_systemd_start` so this should work for you:

```
%:
    dh $@ --with=systemd

override_dh_installinit:
    dh_installinit --name=myapp

override_dh_systemd_start:
    dh_systemd_start --no-start
```

Remember that this will also not stop the service on removal as mentioned in the `--no-start` doc.

Answer (score 1):

In the meanwhile `dh_systemd_start` has been deprecated. As far as I can tell, the current way to solve this problem is by using the same argument on

```
override_dh_installsystemd:
    dh_installsystemd --no-start
```

[as documented here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_installsystemd.1.en.html#no%7E3). There is also the option `--no-enable` if this helps anyone.